# VS2010 x86 and AnyCPU project vs solution setting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment

I have a deployed WPF exe that I have some concern that in the field it is truly running as x86 so I can be assured I am not running into the strange behaviour that people have mentioned when you are set to AnyCPU because of WOW64. 
My project (only assembly in the project, although I do rely on a 32bit dll) settings are:[image]

Yet my Solution Configuration is set to AnyCPU.
[image]

Can I still be confident that my app is just 32bit?

Oh, here are my corflags.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a design flaw in VS2010, it particularly strikes when you converted a project from an earlier version of VS.  The platform name does not in any way affect the bitness of your final process.  It is just a name, it doesn't directly affect any project settings for managed projects.

Only the Project + Properties, Build, "Platform target" setting matters.  Furthermore, only the setting on the EXE project matters, DLLs have to live by whatever bitness was selected by the EXE project when it started up.  So the normal setting for a DLL project is AnyCPU.  And if you want your process to be 32-bit then change the setting on the EXE project to x86.  If you want the Platform name to match then just add another one named "x86", also the default name when you create a new project in VS2010.  Having the platform name match the C# platform target setting is up to you, it is not automatic.  Don't forget to also change the setting on the Release configuration.

The Platform name gets to be important for native projects, C++ projects in particular.  Because they don't support anything like AnyCPU, you need separate builds for them.  The Platform selector is now useful to easily switch between builds.